# What files should be commited in the case of an Eclipse modeling project?

Tags: git, eclipse, eclipse-emf

In your opinion, what Eclipse configuration files need to be included in git commits and what are those that should be ignored?

Specifically, I am talking about an Ecore/Xtext project using Eclipse modeling framework under ubuntu.

The files I am thinking of are :
.DS_Store
.metadata
.classpath
.project
.settings

I have a doubt about
META-INF
build.properties
plugin.properties

And what about .gitignore itself?

I believe generated source files in src and src.gen should be included in commits since I may need to edit them in the future. I am right? Or maybe should I include them only once I edit them?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: The `.classpath` and `.project` files and the `.settings` folder should be committed. You should not have a `.metadata` folder in your project. In the workspace directory there is a `.metadata` folder that must not committed. It is unclear where the [`.DS_Store`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) is coming from as it is macOS related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me preface that many people say you shouldn't commit any IDE specific files to avoid restricting projects to a particular IDE. But in my experience when working with Eclipse plugins/EMF/Xtext projects it makes everything easier to only use Eclipse and include them. You might not need them if you use a pure maven-tycho build process though.

Anyway here is what I would commit.

Project files that should definitely be committed, as these are part of the final product:

- `META-INF` contains important plugin meta data, like the `MANIFEST.MF` which is essential to the build and at runtime
- `plugin.properties` is used to localize the `MANIFEST.MF`

Eclipse-specific files that should be committed:

- `.project` is required to import the projects correctly
- `build.properties` is required to build the project correctly
- `.settings` contains plugin specific metadata, for example which Java versions
- `.classpath` is as far as I know mostly generated and updated from other sources but could contain other information that you need. I never had any issues committing it.

Files that should usually be committed:

- `.gitignore` - it makes sense to have common rules for everyone. If anyone needs their own local ignore pattern, they should use `.git/info/exclude` instead which is never commited.
- `src-gen` - best practices often say that generated files should not be committed but every project I work at some point included this folder. Generating Java classes from large .ecore files can take some time. But even more important is, that if someone changes the model, everyone else has to generate `src-gen` after checkout of that commit. In fast moving projects that means you may have to generate `src-gen` after each checkout. If you checkout older commits or switch branches you have generate `src-gen`. If you forget, your Eclipse workspace will be littered with errors. Generating on checkout could likely be scripted but its still a hassle. So just regenerate `src-gen` when you change the model and spare everyone else from doing it every time. (By the way I would still avoid changing the files manually if possible. It's rarely required and can usually be avoided)

Files that shouldn't be committed:

- `.metadata` in the workspace. This contains e.g. information about projects in the workspace (including local projects not under version control) and likely contains user-specific paths.
- `target` and `bin` folders
- `xtend-gen` if you use Xtend. Unlike `src-gen`, this one folder more ephemeral and is automatically regenerated by Eclipse when building.

Keep in mind that IDE plugins could add additional files that may are or are not needed by others.

You could also take a look at Github's [`.gitignore` template for Eclipse](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Global/Eclipse.gitignore). This template does exclude `.settings` though, which I usually would commit, if everyone in the team uses the same IDE plugins with the same configuration. It also excludes `*.launch` files, which you likely want to commit if your application requires complex launch configuration like often is the case for plugin projects.

Comment: You also need them when using pure Maven build process as Maven is about building and not about editing. All IDEs put these files into the project folder to be shared. Those who tell that you should exclude "IDE-specific files" do this without knowing the purpose of these files.